# what is the difference between "%02s" and "%2s" in C?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
char temp[32] = "";
sprintf(temp, "%02s", "A");
```

but it has warning as: `Warning 566: Inconsistent or redundant format char 's'`, then I changed to code to: `sprintf(temp, "%2s", "A");`, the warning disappeared, what is the difference?

Comment: `0` operation flag for the transformation `s` is undefined. There is no meaning.

Comment: It might be worth mentioniing here, that for the conversion specifier `s` a `' '` can be used to pad with blanks, as the `'0'` is used to pad numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%0` format means "0-padding", but you can't combine that with a string format specifier (`s`), that's undefined.

See [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf):

> 0
>
> The value should be zero padded. For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the converted value is padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks. If the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0 flag is ignored. If a precision is given with a numeric conversion (d, i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored. For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.